# Small extra movement after dragging the Rect node. Is this a bug?

Tags: reactjs, konvajs, react-konva, konva

I'm trying to implement stepped positioning on canvas elements in KonvaJS. Here is the minimal, reproducible example I've created to see the problem better: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-wave-wkz4ut?file=/src/App.tsx

Everything is fine if the Stage is at position `(0, 0)`. But once the Stage position is set to some arbitrary value (either set directly or by dragging the Stage), and the green Rect is dragged, there's a small movement that happens when letting go of the green Rect. This doesn't happen if the `setX()` and `setY()` functions aren't called in the `onDragEnd` prop of the Rect. In my project use case, this is necessary, so removing those calls is not an option.

It seems like the position given to the `dragBoundFunc` prop is not the same as the position given in the `onDragEnd` prop (through `event.target.position()`). Is this a bug? If it isn't, is there a way to retrieve the same position given to the `dragBoundFunc`? Thank you!

Edit: Thank you @lavrton for the answer! Seems I'm going about this the wrong way, I'll post the proper answer once I make it work on my side.

Comment: Can you expand on 'a small movement' please ?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat There's an extra movement on the Rect that happens when you let go of the mouse button. Instead of stopping where you let it go, it moves a little bit more, kinda like inertia. This is more apparent if you drag and hold the Rect for a bit longer in one place then let go.

Comment: Could you modify your sample to maybe log the position while dragging and then when dropped and perhaps compute the difference? It will make it easier to absorb / understand issue and provide a possible test case for any solution.

Answer (score 1):

`dragBoundFunc` always works in absolute positions. It may not be comfortable in some situations. For most of the cases I recommend to use "drag" events only such as `dragmove`.